# SD card files with encrypted data (_CONSOLE text in it), how to get my files back?

Tags: android, encryption, jpeg, sd-card, samsung-mobile

I have an micro SD card, that was in a Galaxy J5 with Android 7, and all the files are messed up now. (jpg, pdf, mp3)

Following characters can be found in the beginning in all of the files, with minor changes in each one.

> <ŕ’Ż4i“µŢî      Ś-         `6Sĺş§uť?ŃÖ0Ü]@Î.0€Ň(QlüŚíď¦îRíb_CONSOLE    sżăm:Ń  ..

.. and then a lot of NULLs following.

The `_CONSOLE` part is there in every file. That's why I think that all files were manipulated with the same method.

I am looking for somebody who has seen this kind of files.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it several times, it appears file based encryption. It is not limited to Android Linux, some NAS devices use it (- eCryptFS file-level encryption).

[image]

Comment: And answer by user7080613 is an answer?! Unbelievable, such nonsense.

Comment: You are right, my mistake, sorry. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the OS has written something along the lines of a table into the start of file/a way to read them. I am pretty sure the data is still there, just not visible. Try opening them via a hex editor and check if the NULL's are really null bytes or unreadable data

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My Galaxy S8 could not longer read the files in the SD card (exFAT) I had encrypted before. I must somehow have deleted the file `.MetaEcfsFile` that contains the Samsung encryption info. See also [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/datarecovery/comments/elay25/android_experts_file_based_encryption/fmpm6h8?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). Btw, the files with the `_CONSOLE` artifact are encrypted with OpenPGP message format ([RFC2440](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2440.txt))

My solution was:

1. Undelete the `.MetaEcfsFile` with [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) from a PC using an SD card reader.
2. Reconnect the Phone via USB cable and copy that file via that connection. Direct copy via SD card reader didn't work. The phone deleted that file again after phone restart.
3. After the file was copied via cable, the SD card files were still encrypted/unreadable, but...
4. The phone menu *Biometrics and security* finally proposed *Decrypt SD card* and after I started the decryption, I got an error but all my files were decrypted and readable again.